# How can I parse my date ranges and then check for collisions?

Tags: java, date

I have to create a booking system type program, where the user inputs a user name (string) followed by the month, date and time they want to book, and then the end month, date and time. So it'll look similar to:

```
John Jul 23 9 Jul 24 18
```

which is

```
user startMonth startDate startTime endMonth endDate endTime
```

I need to be able to implement this so that, I can check if any bookings collide, could someone please give me a guide in how to do this since I'm new to Java.

EDIT: I know how to parse the input, but I don't quite know how to use the date functions in java, and how that would help me check if any bookings collide.

Comment: What is the question exactly? How to parse the date or how to do all of the program?

Comment: do you have a general idea on how to do it and need help with an implementation in java, or do you need a general idea on how to approach this?

Comment: I have parse the date, I just don't understand how to use the date class, and how to store the information into it so I can check if its within a range

Comment: maerics answer is the correct answer. Yet before using SimpleDateFormat you will need to separate the user input in different Strings (user name / date 1 / date 2). Can you input the data in different fields (lines)?

Comment: the input has to be per line as shown, so I've used the split function to parse the string input, and im trying to understand how to use the SimpleDateFormat stuff at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question...  `( start1 <= end2 and start2 <= end1 )`

The `java.util.Date` wraps a `long` value.  use `getTime()` to get that value, for comparisons.

See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestIfDateRangesOverlap

Comment: how would I use my input with getTime?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, parsing and formatting [`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects is handled by objects of type [`DateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), usually [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Review the SimpleDateFormat documentation and try to imagine how you could use Date objects to see if there are any collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the input, you can do it with  String.split method
or more sophisticated way, which I think is better, is by using java regex.

after parsing you can form a string which will contain the date and then to parse it with java date parser.

Answer (score 0):

as maerics already wrote: SimpleDateFormat is your friend ...

split your input in 3 parts like SJuan76 suggested and feed both date parts to SimpleDateFormat's parse method ... that way you can get a Date object for both date parts ...

now to the booking part and that collision checking ...

i'd suggest you create your own class for a reservation or booking or however you want to call it.

you could use a LinkedList to store the objects ...

when you add an object to the list, keep the list sorted by start date ... that way you can see if an inserted object will collide wit another one ... find the location where to insert the new object ... look at the predecessor ... if the start date of the new object is before the predecessors end date we have a collision ... if the new end date is after the successors start date, we have a collision ... if there is no collision, insert the new object at this position in the list ...